# fb.api or fb.ui how to upload photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, upload

I'm using Javascript, my application is publishing to Facebook using FB.ui and FB.api
Recently, I received a mail with the following content:

> It looks like your app, (...) may be posting photos with pre-filled
>   captions. If that's the case, you'll want to remove any default photo
>   captions within the next few days in order to avoid restrictions.
>
> As a reminder, this isn't allowed under the Facebook Platform Policies
>   because we want stories published by apps to represent the user's
>   voice. You can read more about this policy at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration

The functions I use are bellow, and now, after so many test made, I really can't understand which one of the functions is the problem.
I suspect that the function `upload_foto` may be the problem but I am not sure, and if I can't upload photos using javascript FB.api then how can I do that?
Any idea how to solve this?

```
function postToWall(to_user_id, title1, url_to_picture, link_to_open) {
        var control = document.getElementById("my_silverlight");
        //this will publish a story to the specified user or page (post owner is the user not the page)
        FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
            name: title1,
            display: 'iframe',
            link: link_to_open,
            description: 'Some description',
            caption: 'Some caption',
            picture: url_to_picture,
            type: 'photo',
            to: to_user_id
        }, function (response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                control.content.PageName.update_post("success");
            } else {
                control.content.PageName.update_post("error");
            } 
        });
    }

function postToPage(to_user_id, title1, url_to_picture, link_to_open) {
    var control = document.getElementById("my_silverlight");
    //this will publish a story to page if the user is the page's administrator (post owner will be the page itself)
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: title1,
        display: 'iframe',
        link: link_to_open,
        description: 'Some description',
        caption: 'Some caption',
        picture: url_to_picture,
        type: 'photo',
        to: to_user_id,
        from: to_user_id
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            control.content.PageName.update_post("success");
        } else {
            control.content.PageName.update_post("error");
        }
    });
}

function postToGroup_Event(to_profile_id, title1, mes, url_to_picture, link_to_open) {
    var control = document.getElementById("my_silverlight");
    //this will publish a story to a group or an event as the curent user 
    FB.api("/" + to_profile_id + "/feed", 'post', { name: title1, link: link_to_open, description: 'Some description', caption: 'Some caption', picture: url_to_picture, message: mes }, function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            control.content.PageName.update_post("success");
        } else {
            control.content.PageName.update_post("error");
        }
    });
}

function upload_foto(from, to_profile_id, url_to_foto, mess, own_wall) {
    var control = document.getElementById("my_silverlight");
    //this will publish a foto with a message to a profile
    FB.api(to_profile_id + '?fields=access_token', function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            FB.api(to_profile_id + '/photos', 'post', { from: from, url: url_to_foto, message: mess, access_token: response.access_token }, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    control.content.PageName.update_post("success", response.post_id);
                } else {
                    control.content.PageName.update_post("error", "");
                }
            });
        } else {
            control.content.PageName.update_post("error", "");
        }
    }, { scope: '' });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "upload_foto" is the problem.

According with Facebook policies send a pre-filling caption (message) is a violation of Section IV.2 of the Facebook Platform Policies. This policy prohibits apps from pre-filling the caption for any photo published on behalf of a user unless the user created the content earlier in the workflow.

The "message" can not be set up by the app. This means you need to let the user write the message or no include any.